# Why would an io.BytesIO stream close when passed as an argument?

Tags: python, django, stream

I have a Django app where a user POSTs a file. The view grabs the file, passes it to a threaded function and processes it. The problem is, sometimes the io.BytesIO stream gets closed before it can be read and I can't figure out why it gets closed.

I'm processing Excel files using the Xlrd library. For some Excel files that are uploaded, the stream stays open but some close. I don't understand what's going on under the hood to figure out why. What I'm asking for is debugging advice. I can't provide my full code but I've outlined what the code path roughly looks like below.

My Django view grabs a file from a POST request:

```
ufile = request.FILES['upload-file'].file
```

`ufile` is an instance of `io.BytesIO`. I have a function that copies the stream to a named temporary file

```
@contextmanager
def temp_input_file(file_):
  temp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
  shutil.copyfileobj(file_, temp)
  temp.close()
  yield temp.name
  os.unlink(temp.name)
```

This contextmanager decorated function is used a little later. The next step is to create a thread to process the uploaded file:

```
  job.run_job(
    method=process_excel_file,
    uploaded_file=ufile
  )
```

What I'm doing is passing a function `process_excel_file` and the uploaded "file" but actually `io.BytesIO` stream to job.run_job, which creates a thread

```
def run_job(self, method, **kwargs):
  thread = threading.Thread()
  thread.run = lambda : method(
    job_id=self.job_db_record.id,
    **kwargs
  )
  thread.start()
```

So `process_excel_file` is passed into the `method` variable and ufile is in `kwargs`. The function running in the thread, `process_excel_file` looks something like this:

```
def process_excel_file(ufile):
  with temp_input_file(ufile) as temp_file:
    in_book = xlrd.open_workbook(temp_file)
    ... # do stuff with in_book
```

So what happens is when I use the `temp_input_file` context manager function, I get a `ValueError` thrown because the stream is closed. If instead I refactor the code to create the temporary file in the view and pass the temp file name instead of a file-like object, it works because the stream gets closed somewhere after it gets passed to `job.run_job`. Any thoughts on why the stream would close? It's more troubling because some files don't close the stream.

Comment: I have the same on returning, it is ridiculous! I finally decided to call BytesIO::getvalue() and use it further.